# Laravel validation - how to return back with errors from Request on fail?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

On validation fail, I have 2 situations

- one when I display a new error page (this is how it was done before in the app)
- I have a form and I redirect back with input (my problem)

The app is catching the ValidationException in the exceptions Handler - so there is no back with errors for me if a request fails.
Now, I need to return back to the input with errors - from the request class, before it throws the standard ValidationException.

How do I do that from the request class pls?

The code is very basic

I have some rules...

I imagine I need a hook like - validationFailed().. in the request class?

Edit: - not API - regular monolithic PHP

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Auth;

class LocationCodeRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        return [
            'new_location_code' => 'required|string|max:255|exists:xxx,code',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the error messages for the defined validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'new_location_code.not_in' => 'xxx',
            'new_location_code.exists' => 'yyy',
        ];
    }

    //I need something like this
    public function validationFailed()
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($this->validator)->withInput();;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code would be nice to be included, are we talking this in an API context or in a monolithic PHP application with frontend and backend in the same PHP context?

Comment: @mrhn Updated ta - not API

Comment: @alextoader by default Form request redirect back with errors

Comment: I know, unfortunately, (I explained) this is disabled in the exception handler where all ValidationExceptions are caught and an error page is shown.

Comment: try   protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();;
    }

Comment: @JohnLobo almost works :). But now it is doing something weird - it is completing the action like is not failing the validation. It is like the back() means back to the save instead of the form?

Comment: @alextoader you have to catch error in blade file . somethink like \@if($errors->count())
    \@foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <div>{{ $error }}</div>
    \@endforeach
\@endif

Comment: Yes, that part is working. The thing is that it is really saving the data when it should not. So the validation fails - it should not get into the controller and save the data but it gets in the controller and saves the data when I do back()->withErrors...

Answer (score 3):

Normally the FormRequest Class will redirect back to the Form Page with inputs and validation errors. That's the default functionality.

```
public function validationFailed() {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($this->validator)->withInput();;
}
```

You don't require the above code if you are passing the FormRequest class in the POST call of the Form like so

```
use App\Http\Requests\LocationCodeRequest;

public function store(LocationCodeRequest $request) { 
    // Code after validation
}
```

You can try by adding this in the LocationCodeRequest file.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;

protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
        // Add redirection here. Errorbag and Inputs shud be available in session or can be passed here
        //throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that default functionality is disabled on this occasion. The default functionality is that it throws a ValidationException which my app is catching in Exception/Handler and showing an error page.

Comment: Which laravel version are you using ?

Comment: it is version 8